# How to manage the iCloud Document of MAC App

Tags: swift, macos, icloud

The documents provided by APPLE did not make it clear to me. This may be my English level limit. I hope you can help me to get a better understanding of it.

I use the FileManager class to manage the files of icloud, including the methods of copyItem, moveItem, and removeItem. I directly deal with the files in the icloudDocument's address as an ordinary file. After matching with NSMetadataQuery, I compare the modification time and creation time of files, so I managed files, but I found it very bad, because I need to judge whether files need updating, uploading or deleting.

I later found that the FileManager class has Managing iCloud-Based Items, which includes the evictUbiquitousItem, startDownloadingUbiquitousItem, and other methods. It seems to be easy to manage, but it doesn't make me clear.

My problems are now:

1. which is the final file when the local file is not consistent with the icloud file? (there is no convenient method, automatic synchronization)
2. what should I do if the icloud does not exist, but when the local file exists? (delete it directly? Or is it necessary to judge?)
3. how do you know which files are downloaded to the local?